# Raspberry Pi: Python Script doesn't work if autostarted with lxterminal but if started with geany it works just fine. What could be my mistake?

Tags: python

I have a program that's autostarted everytime when my raspberry boots and it should upload data to an API, but everytime it tries to connect it gets an error. I use requests to post my request and it works perfectly fine if i start the program in Geany but i should manage to start it with LXTerminal.

i have already tried to change the python version its started in but it doesn't work and i have tried to change the path.

```
class CSVDataModel:
red = 0
green = 0

def job():
with open('/path/data.csv', "r") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter = ",")
    data = list(reader)
ifile = open('/path/data.csv', "r")
reader = csv.reader(ifile, delimiter = ";")
a = []
for row in reader:
    a.append(row)

payload = CSVDataModel()
payload.red = int(a[0][0])
payload.green = int(a[1][0])
url ="url"+"red="+str(payload.red)+"&green="+str(payload.green)
print(url)
time.sleep(5)
r = requests.post(url, timeout = 5)
print("sent")
with open("/path/data.csv", "w") as csvFile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvFile, delimiter= ' ', lineterminator='\r\n')
    writer.writerow("0")
    writer.writerow("0")
csvFile.close()
print("reset")

schedule.every(1).minutes.do(job)
while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: the window closes instantly after it gets an error and i am unable to read what it says

Comment: Check your environment. Maybe there are different interpreter paths or even `python` versions in Geany and lxterminal (e.g. `python` 3 vs 2), as well as other ENV variables

Comment: make sure it starts with the same working directory. check with `import os` `print(os.getcwd())`

Comment: Instead of running it on your raspberry pi, have you tried running this script on your computer?

Comment: This could be one of those times it's helpful to have your main code in a function. It makes it much easier to wrap in e.g. a `try: ... except Exception as e: traceback.print_exc() finally: input("Script end, hit Enter")` so you can read what sort of error it produces (unless the error is while trying to compile the script, in which case it still narrows it down).

Answer (score 0):

In the comments, you said:

> the window closes instantly after it gets an error and i am unable to read what it says

You you've set it up to run Python in a terminal window somehow?

What you should do instead is open a terminal window, `cd` to the directory where your script is stored and run `python <scriptname>.py` (or maybe `python3 <scriptname>.py`).

Doing it like that should give you a backtrace of the error in the terminal window.

Instead of running Python in a terminal window you could e.g. run it from your `crontab` file, and capture standard output and standard error streams to a file:

```
python scriptname.py >logfile.txt 2>&1
```

That would allow for automation *and* error capture.

Comment: the problem with my crontab is that it doesn't work properly

Comment: Can you edit your question to describe *in detail* how you're running your script when you see the "window closes instantly"? On a Linux machine like a raspberry pi, running a Python script would generally not open a terminal window.

Comment: as i mentioned i start the script using LXTerminal

Comment: Normally, running a script from a terminal should not "close the window instantly" as you describe.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it works in Geany and doesn't from LXTerminal is quite possibly the fact that geany is running your script from the working directory, i.e. the one in which your relative paths correctly resolve. Try either using absolute paths (i.e. `/home/user/path/data.csv`) instead of relative ones or use `os.chdir()` in the script to make sure the working directory is always the correct one.

Comment: i am using absolute paths but i replaced them with "path"

Comment: Oh, nevermind then. In the future when making up paths try to start them with `/` when they're absolute so it's clear to the readers :)

Comment: yeah i am sorry first time asking something here :D